# How post requests get header parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Backend services are working correctly. I'm trying to set the header parameter. But I am making a mistake somewhere. I can't get a response.

Error appearing in console: Request failed with status code 417

How can I solve it?

**PolicyService.js**

```
const getAsosPaymentInfo = (getPolicyAccountInfoRequestDto) => {
  return new Observable((observer) => { // <PaymentInfoResponseDto>
    axiosInstance
      .post(SERVICE_PATH + '/getAsosPaymentInfo', getPolicyAccountInfoRequestDto, {
        headers: { 'sales-channel': 200008, 'agency-code': 10038, 'content-type': 'application/json' }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        observer.next(response.data);
        observer.complete();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
};
```

**policy-payment-info.js**

```
  const req = {
    policyNumber: '1277976920',
    renewalNumber: '01',
    policyTypeExtCode: '800',
    productTypeExtCode: '2000062'
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.location.state.policy.isActive === true) {
      PolicyService.getAsosPaymentInfo(req).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response);
        }
      );
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Headers inside function `getAsosPaymentInfo` seems to be correct. Maybe your backend expect others headers like `'content-type': 'application/json'`?

PS: You could use Postman to execute same post request and see differences

Comment: I added as you said, but the problem persists.